# Use of Terra in Rmd With cache = T

Tags: r, geospatial, terra

This something I had solved for raster, but now it is a bit different with terra, so lets say I am generating an Rmd, and I do the following:

````
---
title: "Test Terra"
author: "Derek Corcoran"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache = T)
library(terra)
```

Lets create a raster

```{r}
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
```
````

So that works great, usually I would read, and do further calculations that could take a long time (hours usually)

and then if I decide I want to do something else I would run this again with an extra chunk:

````
---
title: "Test Terra"
author: "Derek Corcoran"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache = T)
library(terra)
```

Lets create a raster

```{r}
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
```

and now do calculations on it

```{r}
r1 <- r*2
```
````

I understand why this happens, as the object is just a pointer to the temp file which is not longer there, whey I used raster I would solve this using the function `raster::readAll`, and get it over with, but that is not longer an option in Terra it seems.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here (a) caching a SpatRaster and (b) temporary files.

The first one is complicated. A SpatRaster holds a reference to a C++ object. If such an object is saved to disk as-is, it cannot be restored. To deal with this you can first transform a SpatRaster (or SpatVector) using the `terra::wrap` method. This mechanism is used automatically when you do `saveRDS` or `serialize`. But `wrap` is not called with you save an R session, nor by "knitr" when caching; and, either way, you would need to call `rast` to serialize the object again after it is read from disk. There is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648083/can-knitrs-cache-work-with-pointer-objects) about this, and I have now [raised an issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2176) with the knitr developers.

The second issue can be solved in different ways. Forcing data to memory is one (you can use `set.values(x)`), but that may not always be possible. In that case you can explicitly save a file with `writeRaster` or by providing a `filename=` argument to another method. You can also use `terraOptions` set the folder used for temporary files to a permanent location such that they do not get removed when an R session ends.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am amazed on how fast you answer this issues, this helps a lot. I was already exporting the rasters as georiffs, but it is kind of annoying that sometimes there is something in the middle that I have to modify that is not where I would have predicted to read the raster again, but as you said, it is something that should probably be solved by the knitr package and not by you. Thanks